# Areca Palm help! Thanks!

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, palm, areca-palm

Anyone know what could be wrong with my areca palm? I water it when the top soil starts to feel dry so it shouldnt be getting too much water. I also mist it everyday and it is in a room with a south facing window but doesn't get direct light.[image] [[image]][image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrKEW.jpg)Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a closeup picture of the underside of a leaf?

Comment: It ended up being spider mites! I ended up cleaning all the leaves! And trimming the bad ones. I will keep up on it and hopefully it will do well! Is that what you were thinking? Thanks!